# Adding { parseAs: 'string } to addContentTypeParser prevents parsing from finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I am using Firebase with Node and Fastify.  Fastify version 4, Node 18.  I have two parsers.

This one works just fine, it completes and forwards the request to my route.

```
server.addContentTypeParser('application/json', require('./lib/json-parser'))
```

This one starts but never finishes, and it times out.  If I add any parseAs (buffer or string), or if I add the raw-body or fasitfy-raw-body plugin, it times out.

```
server.addContentTypeParser('application/json', { parseAs: 'buffer' }, function (req, body, done) {
  try {
    const newBody = {
      rawBody: body,
    }
    done(null, newBody)
  } catch (error) {
    error.statusCode = 400
    done(error, undefined)
  }
})
```

What could be the issue?  It's not clear to me what Fastify is doing or what I am doing that would possibly cause this issue.

Update: this also times out.

```
server.addContentTypeParser('*', function (req, body, done) {
  var data = ''
  payload.on('data', chunk => { data += chunk })
  payload.on('end', () => { 
    done(null, data)
  })
})
```

Comment: You can't set multiple parser for the same content type, so - to debug it you may set "application/foo" and check if it is called. I general, your code looks good, so do you have a minimal way to reproduce it?

Comment: Oh I didn't set multiple, I just tried two separate ways of adding the parser.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that Firebase might be struggling with the parseAs buffer.

Comment: Changing to concatAs seems to have solved.

Comment: This is definitely related to Firebase already parsing.  I'm not sure why there is a timeout, the Firebase generator runs and doesn't have a next step.  But to solve this, I have simply gotten the firebase request, which in my Fastify setup is request.raw.rawBody (rawBody provided by Firebase as a buffer).

Comment: I needed this for Stripe signature validation (which appears to be an issue for many people).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is that I was using this with a Firebase function which was was trying to parse the response and causing some sort of conflict.  I removed parseAs and I used the firebase raw.rawBody (which in Fastify is the firebase output and rawBody is the unparsed buffer from the firebase function).